# How do render a dropdownl list with options coming from state

Tags: reactjs

I want to display a dynamic drop down list but I am a little confused on how to do it.

I want to iterate through my users like:

```
users.map((user) => {
}
```

Do I have to create another function to do this or can I do it all in a single function?

```
_renderDropdown() {
   const { users } = this.props;

   return (
      <select name="userDdl" onChange={::this._onSelectedUserChange}>
      </select>
   );

}

_onSelectedUserChange(e) {
   console.log('user selected change called...');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
<select name="userDdl" onChange={::this._onSelectedUserChange}>
 {users.map(user => (
  <option key={user.id} value={user.id}>{user.name}</option>
 ))}
</select>
```

Comment: Now it does. 

Answer (score 1):

Here's a minimal example:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    users: ["Elon", "Steve", "Bill"]
  };

  renderOptions() {
    return this.state.users.map(u => {
      return <option value={u}>{u}</option>;
    });
  }

  render() {
    return <select options>{this.renderOptions()}</select>;
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

CodeSandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/wqnw269xq5).

Answer (score 0):

It's your choice where you would like to place the logic. To render the options based on the users, you can do like this:

```
{
 users.map((user, index) => {
  return (
    <option key={index}>{user.value}</option>
  )
 })
}
```

Comment: I wanted to combine it all in a single function, including the select tag.  Is that possible?